Convert shifted value MSB to 1
Assume we have this semicode:
int x = 2 ;//x is not fixed and is not negative
uint8_t val =01100011 ;  
val >>x ===> 00011000    

i need most left two zero turn to 1, so the result will be 11011000
how can i do that programmatically?

The number you presented seems to be uint8_t, is it true for all possible input values?

Why don't you do bit-wise or v |= 11000000 (binary)?

IMO question lacks important details what is actual aim. Is x fixed to 2 or is it dynamic value? Can x be negative? Is x related with those 2 leading  bits set to 1?

Re "Can x be negative?", That would be UB, so one could assume no.

@ikegami my question was about problem specification. When this is clarified then possible UB should be addressed. Fact that there is such UB you are referring to doesn't mean that OP do not need negative x.

@alex, 01100011, an octal constant of type int is too large for uint8_t.  Use 0b01100011 to clearly identify as a binary value.  Such notation is scheduled for C2X.

Are you filling the left-hand side with 1s, or are you wrapping your bit-shift around? If I did "val >> 3" in your pseudocode, would you expect 01101100, or 11101100?

@Marek R, The OP said they wanted to do val >> x, but with a twist. val >> x is UB for negative x. So one can assume x isn't negative. If they want to support negative x, then that would contradict the question. Sure, good to ask for confirmation, but as it stands, x can't be negative.

Since you are dealing with bytes, it's pretty straight-forward:
( (~0xFFu | val) >> x) & 0xFFu

That is, create a bit mask of 0xFFFF-....00 depending on the size of int. OR in the byte value in the ls byte. Shift the whole thing 2 steps to the right. Mask out the ls byte.

Assuming an 8-bit input,
// val >> x, but 1 bits are shifted in instead of 0 bits.
// Constraint: x ≤ 8
uint8_t f( uint8_t val, uint8_t x ) {
   return ( ( 0xFF00u | val ) >> x ) & 0xFFu;
}

chux's answer and Lundin's answer accept larger shift amounts.

& 0xFF; is not needed. You are using unsigned value so conversion is well defined.

I posted an almost identical answer. What if q > 8 though? (Anyway, have a +1 for FGITW.)

@MarekR & 0xFF is useful for quieting pedantic compiler's concern about narrowing.

@MarekR Not necessary, but self-documenting code. In this case it means "I did indeed mean to return a byte not an unsigned integer". Whereas in the case with the mask left out the code means "either I returned the wrong type by accident or I just like to be smug, silently relying on implicit type conversions". The rule of thumb is that code relying on implicit conversions without a word or comment is generally bad and buggy.

@Marek R, Re "& 0xFF; is not needed.", Yeah. But I was signaling what was happening to the OP (and I suppose, any other reader). As Lundin put it, it's self-documenting code, in lieu of an explanation outside of the code.

@ikegami Since p is integer promoted, there's no UB. You can shift as many bits as there's room in an int/unsigned int.

@Lundin, Noted assumption in answer.

To shift in 1's instead of 0's, could flip the bits, do a normal shift, and flip again.   Be sure to use unsigned math.
~(~((unsigned) val) >> x)


You need to shift x times and set x most significant bits.
uint8_t shiftandset(uint8_t val, unsigned x)
{
    if(x <= 8)
    {
        uint8_t mask = -1;
        val >>= x;
        val |= (mask << (8 - x));
    }
    return val;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%hhb\n", shiftandset(0b01100011, 2));
    printf("%hhb\n", shiftandset(0b01100011, 3));
    printf("%hhb\n", shiftandset(0b01100011, 5));
    printf("%hhb\n", shiftandset(0b01100011, 8));
    printf("%hhb\n", shiftandset(0b01100011, 0));
}

https://godbolt.org/z/zvP5PY36M
PS I am using non standard printf format (C23)

I assume OP wants to shift right by a variable x and set the x most significant bits to 1 (i.e. the new ones introduced by the shift).

@chux-ReinstateMonica Low-level programmers eventually start talking in mnemonics... occupational hazard :)
